# virtualenvwrapper.sh doesn't not run

Tags: macos, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I just tried to install virtualenvwrapper and when I 
run the following (as found in the [instructions](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/))

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

It failed with the following :

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: line 347: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: line 347: `workon () {'
```

Anybody else is experimenting this?

Comment: Find out it was a specific problem with my setup (had an alias called workon, then I got 2 python install (thx mac os X) and pip install the librairies in the wrong one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may clean up your Bash shell environment a bit before sourcing /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh.

```
unalias -a
unset -f $(compgen -A function)
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```